# Does the RabbitMQ shovel plugin preserve message ordering?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

I use the RabbitMQ shovel plugin (dynamic shovel, see below) to provide unidirectional messaging between two RabbitMQ brokers over an unreliable WAN link. I see regular connection losses in the RabbitMQ server log.

The relevant portions of the AMQP setup are identical for both brokers: one exchange (fanout, durable) and one queue (durable). The consuming application requires that messages are received in the same order they are produced at the sending side.

The observed behaviour seems to indicate that this is not the case, perhaps due to retransmissions, etc. Does the RabbitMQ shovel pluging preserve message ordering without message loss? What are the required configuration options?

[image: shovel declaration]

Comment: If you have one link then it should preserve ordering. With multiple links, most probably not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ensuring message ordering the following parameters should be configured:

```
 "prefetch-count" : 1
 "ack-mode"       : "on-confirm"
```

**prefetch-count** The maximum number of unacknowledged messages copied over a shovel at any one time. Default is 1000.

**ack-mode** Determines how the shovel should acknowledge messages. If set to **on-confirm** (the default), messages are acknowledged to the source broker after they have been confirmed by the destination. This handles network errors and broker failures without losing messages, and is the slowest option. If set to on-publish, messages are acknowledged to the source broker after they have been published at the destination. This handles network errors without losing messages, but may lose messages in the event of broker failures. If set to no-ack, message acknowledgements are not used. This is the fastest option, but may lose messages in the event of network or broker failures.

For more information related to RabbitMQ's shovel mechanism please refer to the official documentation: https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel-dynamic.html

Comment: This is definitely the best you can get. But one should not expect RabbitMQ messages to always be perfectly ordered anyways. RabbitMQ only gives strong guarantees on orders in very specific conditions. More information about this in RabbitMQ [Semantics](https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html) documentation page; search for `Message ordering guarantees` section.

Comment: How can I set prefetch-count?  Docs say "src-prefetch-count" but I cannot set either property using UI or management API